# How to implement quicksort with two objects

Tags: java, object, quicksort

I am trying to sort two object arrays. One array is a `Bolt[]` array, the other is a `Nut[]` array. I cannot compare a Bolt to another Bolt. I can only compare a bolt to a nut, and vice versa.

I think the solution is to use some adapted version of quicksort, but I am having trouble implementing it. Given the code I have written, `MatchNutsBolt`, I am not sure what I can do to make it work:

```
int pivot = partition(nut, low, hi, bolt[hi])
```

I cant think of how to use, say, a `Nut` pivot, then traverse the `Bolt[]` list, then use the matching `Bolt`s pivot and traverse though the `Nuts[]` list, thereby sorting both arrays with an average `O(n log n)` run time.

```
public class MatchNutsBolts {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random r = new Random(20);

     Bolt[] listOfBolts = NutsBolts.makeRandomBolts(r, 7);
     Nut[] listOfNuts = NutsBolts.makeMatchingNuts(r, listOfBolts);

     int low = 0;
     int hi = listOfBolts.length-1;


     match(listOfNuts, listOfBolts, low, hi);

     boolean x = NutsBolts.correctFit(listOfNuts, listOfBolts);
     System.out.print(x+" ");
}

public static void match(Nut[] nut, Bolt[] bolt, int low, int hi)
{
     if (low < hi)
        {
            // Choose last character of bolts array for nuts partition.
            int pivot = partition(nut, low, hi, bolt[hi]); //here is where im having a problem

            // Now using the partition of nuts choose that for bolts
            // partition.
            partition(bolt, low, hi, nut[pivot]);

            match(nut, bolt, low, pivot-1);
            match(nut, bolt, pivot+1, hi);
        }
}
private static int partition(Bolt[] bolt, int low, int high, Nut pivot)
{
    int i = low;
    Bolt temp1, temp2;
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        //int  cmp = Nut.compareTo(bolt[j]);

        if (bolt[j].getDigit(i) < pivot.getDigit(i)){
            temp1 = bolt[i];
            bolt[i] = bolt[j];
            bolt[j] = temp1;
            i++;
        } else if(bolt[j].getDigit(i) == pivot.getDigit(i)){
            temp1 = bolt[j];
            bolt[j] = bolt[high];
            bolt[high] = temp1;
            j--;
        }
    }
    temp2 = bolt[i];
    bolt[i] = bolt[high];
    bolt[high] = temp2;

    // Return the partition index of an array based on the pivot 
    // element of other array.
    return i;
}
}
 class Bolt {

final private static int SIZE = 7;

private int[] notches;

// A Bolt object is basically a seven digit number.
public Bolt(Random r) {
    notches = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<notches.length; i++)
        notches[i] = r.nextInt(10);
}

// A standard constructor given the information stored in a Bolt.
public Bolt(int[] digits) {
    notches = new int[digits.length];
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        notches[i] = digits[i];
}

// Needed to access each digit of a Bolt.
public int getDigit(int i) {
    return notches[i];
}

// Made this work the opposite of the corresponding comparison. Surprisingly
// it's not a circular definition, just a consistent one.
public int compareTo(Nut n) {
    return -n.compareTo(this);
}

// Return a matching Nut. A matching nut is one who's number has each digit
// be its complement. A complement to a digit is its difference from 9.
public Nut getMatchingNut() {
    int[] tmp = new int[SIZE];

    // We set each digit for the match.
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        tmp[i] = 9 - notches[i];

    // Now create the object and return it.
    Nut match = new Nut(tmp);
    return match;
}

// For debugging purposes.
/*public void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) 
        System.out.print(notches[SIZE-1-i]);
}*/
}
  class Nut {

final private static int SIZE = 7;

private int[] notches;

// A Nut object is basically a seven digit number.
public Nut(Random r) {
    notches = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<notches.length; i++)
        notches[i] = r.nextInt(10);
}

// A standard constructor given the information stored in a Nut.
public Nut(int[] digits) {
    notches = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        notches[i] = digits[i];
}

// Need this to access a single digit.
public int getDigit(int i) {
    return notches[i];
}

// Here we define a compareTo.
public int compareTo(Bolt n) {
    int[] tmp = new int[SIZE];
    int carry = 0;
    boolean low = false;

    // Add up the numbers stored in this and n.
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        tmp[i] = (carry + notches[i] + n.getDigit(i))%10;
        carry = (carry + notches[i] + n.getDigit(i))/10;
        if (tmp[i] < 9)
            low = true;
    }

    // Our sum is a bunch of 9s, so we've got a match!
    if (tmp[SIZE-1] == 9 && !low)
        return 0;

    // Our sum is too big, so make this nut too big.
    else if (carry > 0)
        return 1;

    // Opposite case.
    else 
        return -1;  
}

// Works just like the mirror method in the Bolt class.
public Bolt getMatchingBolt() {
    int[] tmp = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        tmp[i] = 9 - notches[i];
    return new Bolt(tmp);
}

// For debugging purposes.
/*public void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) 
        System.out.print(notches[SIZE-1-i]);
}*/

}
 class NutsBolts {

    // Returns true iff each nut and each corresponding bolt in the two
    // respective arrays match eacy other.
    public static boolean correctFit(Nut[] nuts, Bolt[] bolts) {

        // Try out each corresponding nut and bolt.
        for (int i=0; i<nuts.length; i++)   

            // See if these don't match.
            if (nuts[i].compareTo(bolts[i]) != 0)
                return  false;

        // If we get here, they all matched.
        return true;
    }

    // Creates an array of Bolt objects with size number of elements utilizing
    // r.
    public static Bolt[] makeRandomBolts(Random r, int size) {

        // Allocate space for our bolts,
        Bolt[] tmp = new Bolt[size];

        // Just create each object here and return the array.
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            tmp[i] = new Bolt(r);
        return tmp;
    }

    // Creates an array of matching nuts to the array of bolts passed in.
    // It scrambles the nuts though, so that they are no longer in the correct
    // locations.
    public static Nut[] makeMatchingNuts(Random r, Bolt[] bolts) {

        // Create the array, and add in each matching nut.
        Nut[] tmp = new Nut[bolts.length];
        for (int i=0; i<bolts.length; i++) {
            tmp[i] = bolts[i].getMatchingNut();
        }   

        // Here we mix the array of nuts up.
        for (int i=0; i<3*bolts.length; i++) {

            // Get two random indexes.
            int index1 = r.nextInt(bolts.length);
            int index2 = r.nextInt(bolts.length);

            // Swap them!
            Nut store = tmp[index1];
            tmp[index1] = tmp[index2];
            tmp[index2] = store;
        }

        // Return our array of mixed up, but matching nuts.
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What would a sorted array containing both nuts and bolts look like? How would it be sequenced? What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: How would you go about sorting these two object arrays basically, but you cannot compare a nut to a nut or a bolt to a bolt,

Comment: You can only compare a nut to a bolt, and this question usually calls for using a quicksort, which i have tried implementing, but i havent been able to do it correctly

Comment: A sort implies there is a 'strict ordering'. If you can strictly order a bolt in relation to a nut, and nut in relation to a bolt, why can you not order a bolt in relation to a bolt? 

Also note your code has some significant formatting problems preventing us from compiling it without making some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Question->
Write a Scilab program to solve the following problem:
Nuts & Bolts Problem (Lock & Key problem) using Quick Sort. Given a set of n nuts of
different sizes and n bolts of different sizes. There is a one-one mapping between nuts and bolts. Match nuts and bolts efficiently.
Constraint: Comparison of a nut to another nut or a bolt to another bolt is not allowed. It means a nut can only be compared with a bolt and a bolt can only be compared with a nut to see which one is bigger/smaller.

Answer->

```
    n = length(arr);  // Get the length of the input array
    
    if n <= 1
        sortedarray = arr;  // If the array has 1 or fewer elements, it's already sorted
        return
    end
    
    pivot = arr(1);  // Choose the first element as the pivot
    left = [];
    right = [];
    
    for i = 1:n
        if arr(i) < pivot
            left = [left, arr(i)];  // Elements smaller than the pivot go to the left
        elseif arr(i) > pivot
            right = [right, arr(i)];  // Elements greater than the pivot go to the right
        end
    end
    
    left = quicksort(left);   // Recursively sort the left subarray
    right = quicksort(right); // Recursively sort the right subarray
    
    sortedarray = [left, pivot, right];  // Combine the sorted subarrays with the pivot
end

nuts = [9,0,6,7,1];
bolts = [7,1,0,9,6];

//User Input
//for i = 1:5
//    message = sprintf("Enter Size of Nut %d :", i);
//    nuts(i) = input(message);  // Input nut sizes
//end

//for i = 1:5
//    message = sprintf("Enter Size of Bolt %d :", i);
//    bolts(i) = input(message);  // Input bolt sizes
//end

sorted_nuts = quicksort(nuts);    // Sort nuts
sorted_bolts = quicksort(bolts);  // Sort bolts

for i = 1:5
    printf("Nut[%d] Matches With Bolt[%d]\n", sorted_nuts(i), sorted_bolts(i));  // Match nuts with bolts
end

//Output->
//Nut[0] Matches With Bolt[0]
//Nut[1] Matches With Bolt[1]
//Nut[6] Matches With Bolt[6]
//Nut[7] Matches With Bolt[7]
//Nut[9] Matches With Bolt[9]
```